# How to draw routes in tableau with line thickness indicating the cost incurred for that route?

Tags: google-maps, data-visualization, data-analysis, tableau-api, gis

I have transport/logistics data which I am trying to visualize using mapping capability of Tableau. I have data at route level i.e origin & destination combinations defined as city, country level for Europe & UK.I have information about cost & volume flow across different origin and destination points.

I know we can draw straight lines from one point to another if we have the lat-long data for each point. Referring to the link below 
http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/using-path-shelf-pattern-analysis

I have three questions:
1. Is there an easy way to get the zip codes and latitude-longitude data along with distance between all points in my data? I know SAS directory has the data for US zip codes but I am working for Europe & UK locations

1. How to change color or thickness of lines based on the cost incurred or volume transported on a particular route?
2. Can I draw actual road distance between two points? I mean not the straight displacement line but the route similar to how Google Map shows.

Please share your knowledge nuggets or experience around this.

Thanks,
Nisha

Comment: You're using google.maps API v3? Yo can draw the actual road distance using the DirectionService but it has limitations only 8 waypoints (or 23 for business version) in order to get the draw you want

Comment: I have a huge shipment data with more than 5000 possible combinations of origin and destination.I know there is a way I can link/overlay google maps with Tableau, but I do not know how to achieve this for entire data. I tried working with Google Earth but even that has limitation for number of way points.

Comment: Is draw each one of combinations in a single line (Polyline) an option?

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I can try that but then I would need data for all the interim locations between origin and destination that the polyline would connect. Isn't it?

Comment: well, no you can draw a Polilyne with only two points (origin and destination). The line will be straight since you don't have more information. Get a look a my comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20392446/drawing-aerial-routes-for-flights-on-google-maps-api-between-two-markers#comment30456366_20392446).
I ask you the same question, where are you data coming from? You have only the origin/destination or your vehicles have a GPS sensor that could help in determine the real route?

Comment: From your comment, the idea I got was if I have all interim data points, a series of polylines can be drawn. These will also be straight lines between 2 points but if we look at the path from origin to destination it would be formed by many polylines connected.....Ans to your ques related to data, I only have the origin & destination w/o any information on real route, but of course we know that the actual route will be more or less similar to what the google map shows. So, the complication lies is integrating our data with the route information on google maps and plotting it on tableau.

Comment: Well, you still can make 5000 request with DirectionService, depends on your business invoice plan. It well be long but could works.

Comment: Is you data fixed all long, I mean you want to draw this only once with the same information (group of cities)?
What you can make is request one time all the combinations and store the path in a database, then use this information to draw the polilynes. If your data don't change every minute, say, it change one a day that could be a good solution (in performance an invoice amount)